# AppBar in Flutter doesn't show

Tags: android, dart, flutter, appbar

I'm trying to implement an AppBar to a page of my app, and it doesn't show. I've tried dabbling with the styles.xml file and the Android Manifest, but to no avail. I'm guessing there's a different way to handle AppBars in Flutter.

Here's my code:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:kain_app/utils/my_navigator.dart';
    import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
    import 'package:kain_app/services/user_management.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';


    class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      HomeScreenState createState() {
        return HomeScreenState();
      }

        @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text("Kain"),
          ),
          )
        );
      }
    }

    class HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen>{
    @override
      noSuchMethod(Invocation invocation) {
        return super.noSuchMethod(invocation);
      }
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context){
      return new Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        body: new Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 110.0, 15.0, 0.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'You are now logged in.',
                      style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily:'Montserrat', fontSize: 80.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700)
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              child: new Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new OutlineButton(
                    onPressed: (){
                      FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut().then((value) {
                        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/login');

                      }).catchError((e) {
                        print(e);
                      });
                    },
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.red[900], style: BorderStyle.solid, width: 4.0,),
                      child: Text('Logout',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      ),
                      ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
      }
    }
```

The AppBar I declared right after HomeScreenState doesn't get rendered.
[You can see the output here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5fGc.png)

How do I unhide the appBar (if that's a thing?). It's my first time coding in Flutter and I'm still learning. Thank you all!

Comment: That because you have two Scaffold and also You have a build method in the statefullWidget. Instead add createstate() to StatefullWidget. https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/interactive

Comment: @Blasanka Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment you're using 2 [Scaffold](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html) and using a build method inside the Stateful Widget. The documentation stated that:

> The Scaffold is designed to be a top level container for a
> [MaterialApp](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp-class.html). This means that adding a Scaffold to each route on a
> Material app will provide the app with Material's basic visual layout
> structure.
>
> It is typically not necessary to nest Scaffolds.

[As a general rule of thumb: use only one Scaffold per Route/screen.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60562085)

You may want to consider something like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(HomeScreen());
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomeScreenState createState() {
    return HomeScreenState();
  }
}

class HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  noSuchMethod(Invocation invocation) {
    return super.noSuchMethod(invocation);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: new Text("Kain"),
        ),
        body: new Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 110.0, 15.0, 0.0),
                    child: Text('You are now logged in.',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                            fontSize: 80.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700)),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              child: new Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new OutlineButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                      style: BorderStyle.solid,
                      width: 4.0,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      'Logout',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]